# PHP CLI - Ask for User Input or Perform Action after a Period of Time

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a PHP script, where I ask the user to select an option: Basically something like:

```
echo "Type number of your choice below:";

echo "  1. Perform Action 1";
echo "  2. Perform Action 2";
echo "  3. Perform Action 3 (Default)";

$menuchoice = read_stdin();

if ( $menuchoice == 1) {
    echo "You picked 1";
    }
elseif ( $menuchoice == 2) {
    echo "You picked 2";
    }
elseif ( $menuchoice == 3) {
    echo "You picked 3";
    }
```

This works nicely as one can perform certain actions based on user input.

But I would like to expand this so that if the user **does not type** something within 5 seconds, the default action will run automatically without any further action from the user.

Is this at all possible with PHP...? unfortunately I am a beginner on this subject.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Hernando

Comment: You might want to use [PHP's ncurses](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php), since rebuilding this functionality from scratch would be difficult.

Comment: If you are using stream functions to read from stdin then you should be able to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025223/php-cli-get-user-input-while-still-doing-things-in-background solves your problem

Comment: Thank you guys... Waleed, ncurses to me is what I do is when someone cuts me off in traffic... ; ) looks like a semester long college course to me... Anigel, I am trying to digest what you recommend. Gordon, I had seen that post before and it does not really help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`stream_select()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) for that. Here comes an example.

```
echo "input something ... (5 sec)\n";

// get file descriptor for stdin 
$fd = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

// prepare arguments for stream_select()
$read = array($fd);
$write = $except = array(); // we don't care about this
$timeout = 5;

// wait for maximal 5 seconds for input
if(stream_select($read, $write, $except, $timeout)) {
    echo "you typed: " . fgets($fd) . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "you typed nothing\n";
}
```

Comment: hek2mgl - this works like a charm... Thank you!! I do not really understand what it all does, but I can drop this right into my script. Thank you again!!

Comment: @Hernandito `stream_select()` returns `false` if no input has been done in `$timeout` secs.. Note my console package at [github](https://github.com/metashock/Jm_Console/). It should be helpful for you.. I've just added a feature request to implement the timeout. Will implement soon :)..

Answer (score 0):

To make hek2mgl code fit exactly to my sample above, the code needs to look like this...:

```
echo "input something ... (5 sec)\n";

// get file descriptor for stdin
$fd = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

// prepare arguments for stream_select()
$read = array($fd);
$write = $except = array(); // we don't care about this
$timeout = 5;

// wait for maximal 5 seconds for input
if(stream_select($read, $write, $except, $timeout)) {
//    echo "you typed: " . fgets($fd);
        $menuchoice = fgets($fd);
//      echo "I typed $menuchoice\n";
        if ( $menuchoice == 1){
                echo "I typed 1 \n";
        } elseif ( $menuchoice == 2){
            echo "I typed 2 \n";
        } elseif ( $menuchoice == 3){
            echo "I typed 3 \n";
        } else {
            echo "Type 1, 2 OR 3... exiting! \n";
    }
} else {
    echo "\nYou typed nothing. Running default action. \n";
}
```

**Hek2mgl many thanks again!!**