# Run php script in terminal until a key is pressed

Tags: php, terminal, console-application, readline

I'm currently writing a terminal game in php and I have faced the real struggle: how can I make my script run freely UNTIL I press a (specific) key?

I know I can take user input with `readline()` etc. but how can I pause a already running script with pressing a key?

Comment: I can't quite hazard an answer, but maybe review [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) and consider [`pcntl_signal`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) as a way to handle a signal sent to the forked child's process? Not sure how to marry readline() with this. But a couple of thoughts all the same!

Comment: PHP is not an event based language so you can't simply keep running regular code. What you can do continue to loop over a block of code then check for input after each pass - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025223/php-cli-get-user-input-while-still-doing-things-in-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use PHP [generators](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) to multitask your game. 
Look at this article [Cooperative multitasking using coroutines (in PHP!)](https://nikic.github.io/2012/12/22/Cooperative-multitasking-using-coroutines-in-PHP.html). There is also library https://github.com/recoilphp/recoil - an asynchronous coroutine kernel for PHP 7, which might help you to write asynchronous tasks.

As a proof of the concept, you can try this script, which is far from perfect. The implementation of the task and scheduler is taken from the article.

```
//Tested on PHP 7.1.11 and MacOS


class Task {
    protected $taskId;
    protected $coroutine;
    protected $sendValue = null;
    protected $beforeFirstYield = true;

    public function __construct($taskId, Generator $coroutine) {
        $this->taskId = $taskId;
        $this->coroutine = $coroutine;
    }

    public function getTaskId() {
        return $this->taskId;
    }

    public function setSendValue($sendValue) {
        $this->sendValue = $sendValue;
    }

    public function run() {
        if ($this->beforeFirstYield) {
            $this->beforeFirstYield = false;
            return $this->coroutine->current();
        } else {
            $retval = $this->coroutine->send($this->sendValue);
            $this->sendValue = null;
            return $retval;
        }
    }

    public function isFinished() {
        return !$this->coroutine->valid();
    }
}


class Scheduler {
    protected $maxTaskId = 0;
    protected $taskMap = []; // taskId => task
    protected $taskQueue;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->taskQueue = new SplQueue();
    }

    public function newTask(Generator $coroutine) {
        $tid = ++$this->maxTaskId;
        $task = new Task($tid, $coroutine);
        $this->taskMap[$tid] = $task;
        $this->schedule($task);
        return $tid;
    }

    public function schedule(Task $task) {
        $this->taskQueue->enqueue($task);
    }

    public function run() {
        while (!$this->taskQueue->isEmpty()) {
            $task = $this->taskQueue->dequeue();
            $task->run();

            if ($task->isFinished()) {
                unset($this->taskMap[$task->getTaskId()]);
            } else {
                $this->schedule($task);
            }
        }
    }
}



function game($state) {
    while (true) {

        if($state->isTheGamePaused === true) {
            echo "The game is paused\n";
        } else {
            echo "Game is running\n";
        }
        yield;
    }
}

function pauseKeyListener($state) {
    readline_callback_handler_install('', function() { });
    while (true) {
        $r = [STDIN];
        $w = NULL;
        $e = NULL;
        $n = stream_select($r, $w, $e, null);
        if ($n && in_array(STDIN, $r)) {
            $pressedChar = stream_get_contents(STDIN, 1);

            // Pause the game if the 'p' is pressed
            if($pressedChar === 'p') {
                $state->isTheGamePaused = true;
            //Resume the game if the 'r' is pressed
            } elseif ($pressedChar === 'r') {
                $state->isTheGamePaused = false;
            }

            echo "Char read: $pressedChar\n";
        }
        yield;
    }
}

$state = new stdClass();
$state->isTheGamePaused = false;

$scheduler = new Scheduler;

$scheduler->newTask(game($state));
$scheduler->newTask(pauseKeyListener($state));

$scheduler->run();
```

Comment: wow, this is a fantastic approach. Tested your code anв it works like a charm. Gonna investigate this method deeper and use it in my application, thanks so much