# Is there really no way to capture a "kill signal" in Windows in PHP CLI?

Tags: php, windows

Mission: I need to be able to execute a little bit of code when my PHP CLI scripts are "killed"/closed (usually by me Xing down their windows, or from the PC shutting down or rebooting). Ideally, I would want to also be able to instruct the OS to wait as it performs the last bits of some important job, but I've essentially given up on that "dream"...

Problem: Handling such signals in PHP is apparently done with the "PCNTL" extension, which *isn't available for Windows at all*! This in spite of the fact that PHP is called "cross-platform".

Although the whole point of what I'm doing is for it to be completely OS-agnostic (no, that doesn't mean "runs on any Linux distro", but all current/supported OSes, or at the very least Windows and Mac), I would in this case accept a solution that is Windows-specific. Not happily, but still...

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals. Applications that create windows (including message-only 'windows' that have no actual window that can be displayed) use messages such as `WM_CLOSE`. These are delivered to the message queue of the thread that owns the window, so it's sort of like signals, except it's not asynchronous.

Comment: Console applications generally don't create windows. They're attached to a console that's hosted by conhost.exe. When the console window is sent `WM_CLOSE`, the console host instructs the session manager (csrss.exe) to create a thread in each of the console's client processes. This thread starts at a routine that calls the list of registered handler functions, up to the default handler that calls `ExitProcess`. The process has 5 seconds for one of the handlers to exit before the server terminates it forcefully via `TerminateProcess`.

Comment: The handler function is passed the event type such as `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` if the user typed Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, and `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` if the console window is closing.

Comment: If a console application is using Microsoft's C runtime library, a handler is registered that maps Ctrl+C to `SIGINT` and all others to `SIGBREAK`. Handlers for these emulated 'signals' can be set via the C `signal` function.

Comment: Well, thanks for those tidbits of information, but what is the conclusion? Is there something I can actually do?

Comment: I have never used PHP. My hope was that this info might be the basis or starting point of an answer from someone who knows PHP and how it's implemented in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact solution to your problem but perhaps can be a workaround solution.
If you just want to close some handles, connections, etc.

[register_shutdown_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

This solution is very limited

1. there is no guarantee how many time is given to your script inside the callback
2. you really should not use any calls to other functions inside the callback -
   i noticed unpredictable behavior. Sometimes there was no problem and sometimes calls were not executed or only some of them - that was long time ago and by using PHP5.6 - don't know how the behavior is of PHP v7.x
3. due to point 1. keep your code as simple and short as possible. Perfectly just 10-20 procedural lines. No objects creation, no calls to other functions, avoid static classes as well.
4. it is up to you to check weather the script shutdown is because it simply ended or there was a problem ot it was terminated.
   callback passed to shutdown_function will always be called at the end of script.
   a quick and dirty trick is to put at the end of your script a global variable that is set to true.
   if a callback registered by shutdown function is called it checks if that variable is set to true.
   and if so it considers that script is closed normally and if not then an error occurred or script was terminated.

the good side is that this solution once working should be completely independent of target OS.

The second solution to your problem is to use Docker on Windows and Linux and build your application as docker container that starts FROM linux distribution that has the extension PCNTL or using any PHP docker image to start [FROM](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) and install the extension on your own by creating a specific Dockerfile. 
In this approach no matter if the application is run on Windows or Linux you have the PCNTL extension available.

PHP applications in docker can be run from command line almost with the same convenience as standalone php application using a php installed on the host system. So Docker approach seems to be much better.

Comment: I am aware of register_shutdown_function(). From the manual: "Note: Shutdown functions will not be executed if the process is killed with a SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal."

Comment: As for Docker, I've attempted to learn about/install/use that numerous times and never got anywhere. It seems like vaporware that doesn't even exist, since its desktop application is completely nonsensical and the "guide"/documentation is a complete clusterduck that I was completely unable to decipher. :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "desktop application". I personally use docker via linux CLI and works perfectly fine. Besides running php scripts as CLI, I am able to start Apache and Nginx and serve them on localhost. I'm able even to run a GUI applications inside a docker and expose their graphic interface so they look to the user as if they ware run without any Docker whatsoever. But this is linux and I run docker only via CLI mode in Terminal. Usually by writing short scripts so I dont need to type to much the same commands.

Comment: Hmm. It sure *sounds* like Docker is fantastic, and maybe I'm just stupid or something, but I simply never get anywhere when I try to start using it. I can't get a grasp of what it *is* beyond the abstract description; in practical terms, I don't know what I'm supposed to do. They don't do a good job at explaining things clearly.

Comment: @user11555230 Perhaps the whole approach can be changed and you can write your cli app the way you send it user input command to close it instead of termination signal. If so check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025223/php-cli-get-user-input-while-still-doing-things-in-background)

Comment: Hmm. That is interesting for other reasons, actually, but in regards to this particular problem, I don't really see the connection?